# Bluetooth sudenly stopped turning on Aspire S5-371T Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, acer

My integrated bluetooth worked. One time it got stuck rebooting over and over again. It repaired itself. Other times it would turn off and could not be turned on until I restarted the computer or installed the updates. What can I do to try to fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`